# Sonarqube ps value error after upgrade to 7.1

Tags: sonarqube

I upgraded from SonarQube 6.7 via 6.7.3 to 7.1.
We use the developer edition with branch support.
Everything worked fine. But when I now open the tab Measures or Activity within a project we get the error "'ps' value (9999) must be less than 500".
Where do I find this value? In database I didn't find anything with this name.

Comment: can you post more info like a detailed log here, please? may be running the sonar analysis with -X switch will give more info.

Answer (score 0):

`ps` is a page size parameter used in API calls and it is usually limited to 500.

You can find which API call uses invalid page size by looking for calls with status code 400 in `logs/access.log`.

Comment: Thanks. I received the 400 for "GET /api/metrics/search?ps=9999 HTTP/1.1". Where do I change the value?